# How to display an error on a page after submitted form times out?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm working on an angular form that submits data to my back-end rest service written using Spring Boot. I need to add a feature that displays an error in case of failure in data submission after a certain duration of time. Currently, the page that has the form keeps loading forever with no error displayed on the form. I want to use the timeouts feature for Rxjs but I don't know how to implement it.

My code snippet for the specific form submit is as follows:

```
this.apiService.afisEnroll(applicant).subscribe(data => {
  if (data.response_code == 210) {
    this.blockUI.stop();
    console.log(`applicant %s enrolled successfully`, applicant.pbuNo);
    var obj = JSON.stringify(this.applicants[this.applicants.length - 1]);
    if (obj == JSON.stringify(applicant)) {
      console.log("this is the last applicant");
      this.captureEnrollmentDetailsForCOMPAS();
    }
  }
  else {
    this.blockUI.stop();
    return this.toast.error("Applicant is already enrolled");
  }
},
  (err) => {
    console.error(err);
    this.blockUI.stop();
    return this.toast.error("error enrolling applicant");
  });
```

Comment: Welcome codeslayer i think should check rxjs timeout example it'll help you out https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/utility/timeout.html

Comment: @HassanSiddiqui I have seen it. How do I implement it in my current code snippet? Do I need to use the whole code block?

Comment: @codeslayer I have updated the code here please check and let me know is this what you want:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-t6z13c-tqrjgi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Make a varible bolean type initially assign it false like
>   var codeExecute =false;
>   do yor all work in

```
   setTimeout(function() {
    this.apiService.afisEnroll(applicant).subscribe(data => {
        if (data.response_code == 210) {
            codeExecute =true;  // addition code
             this.blockUI.stop();
            console.log(`applicant %s enrolled successfully`,applicant.pbuNo);
            if 
                (JSON.stringify(this.applicants[this.applicants.length - 1]) == 
                    JSON.stringify(applicant)) {
                    console.log("this is the last applicant");
                    this.captureEnrollmentDetailsForCOMPAS();
                }
                            //this.applicantenrolledsuccessfully = true;
                        }
                        else {
                            this.blockUI.stop();
                            return this.toast.error("Applicant is already enrolled");
                        }
                    }, (err) => {
                        console.error(err);
                        this.blockUI.stop();
                        return this.toast.error("error enrolling applicant");
                    });
}, 1000);
if(!codeExecute){
    codeExecute = true;
    return this.toast.error("Time out error Please try again");
}
```

Comment: Thanks. The timeout function however shows the times out message even after the data gets submitted. How can I fix this?

Comment: Welcome.
For this case you have to manage data from back end if you  are using node js for back end so use promise to manage this case.